# Big Sur Beta 5 clean reinstall stuck on macOS Update Assistant

Tags: macos, software-update, beta, big-sur

I’m running a macOS Big Sur Beta installer from Recovery after erasing my drive on Mac mini 2014, and after running a Reinstall macOS utility for over an hour, this Update Assistant appeared. The progress bar is not moving, wireless keyboard and trackpad disconnected, I can’t find any information on this utility on the web.

I’m aware of various rebooting methods, instead, I’d like to find out if anyone is familiar with the said assistant and possible reasons for its appearance on my screen.

[image]

Comment: How does this relate to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400250/installing-big-sur-beta-5-on-catalina-stuck-on-black-screen?

Comment: This is a separate issue, since I’m running a clean install after erasing my disks. Your given link shows my question relating to installing Beta onto Catalina, which presents a standalone set of issues.

Comment: I understand. Is the other question still relevant?

Comment: Yes, I might need to run Beta on Catalina again if the current method also fails, so I’d like to know how to avoid the errors, also if they relate to wider problems with my setup.